# Why, after using sequelize and passing to ejs, would only the first object have a value while all of the others appear empty?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, ejs

I am trying to extract data from different tables and save data inside different objects using `sequelize` in `node.js`. The problem is that when I pass these objects to `ejs` and try to access their properties, all of the other objects here are empty except one.

```
var doctors, patient;
Consultant.findAll().then((data) => {
        if (data) {
            doctors = data;
        } else {
            console.log('No data found');
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        Patient.findAll().then((data) => {
            if (data) {
                patient = data;
            } else {
                console.log('No data found');
            }
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(patient);
        res.render('save', { user: req.user, consultants: doctors, patients: patient });
    });
```

When I try to access the `consultants` object's properties in ejs it shows an empty object and only the `patients` object has values init. I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize queries execute in asynchronous(non-blocking) manner which means that execution does not wait for `sequelize` queries to complete but instead executes the `res.render` statement resulting in some empty objects to pass into your ejs view.

To solve your problem you have to force the complete execution of sequelize queries before going to `res.render` statement.

Node Js has `async` plugin which you can solve your problem. You can install this plugin by npm command as

```
 npm install -g async
```

After installing this plugin you have to import it into your js file as

```
const async = require('async');
```

Now you can use `parallel` or `series` function of this plugin. `Parallel` function runs all the functions present inside an array or object, in parallel manner. Where `series` function waits for first function to execute and then executes next function inside an array or object.In your case inside `parallel` or `series` you can place your sequelize queries. After execution of all the functions inside of `parallel` or `series` function(in your case  all sequelize queries), a final function calls where you can place your `res.render` statement.

Heres the code that can solve your problem

```
var Locals = {};

    asynco.parallel([
        (done) => {
            Consultant.findAll().then(data => {
                Locals.Consultant = data;
                done();
            });
        },
        (done) => {
            Patient.findAll().then(data => {
                Locals.Patient = data;
                done();
            });
        }        
       ], (err) => {

            res.render('save', { user: req.user, consultants: Locals.Consultant, patients: Locals.Patient });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using async await makes the code simpler and easy to understand. Since the consultant and patient calls are independent, we can call them in parallel. And it will decrease the execution time and hence increasing the performance.

```
async () => {
    var doctors, patient;
    const promise_array = [ Consultant.findAll(), Patient.findAll()];
    const [doctors, patient] = await Promise.all(promise_array);
    res.render('save', { user: req.user, consultants: doctors, patients: patient });
}
```

Comment: Yes, this also can solve the problem. And in case if both `sequelize queries` are not independent then you can use `await` keyword before each `sequelize query` and place queries in order in which you want to execute them.